# Using play! cache on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, playframework

I'm trying to use Cache in my app. Following the Play! documentation, I've added the following to my application.conf:

```
memcached=enabled
memcached.host=127.0.0.1:11211
```

It seems to work in the local development server, but when it is deployed in Google App Engine, I'm getting the following error in the logs:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.SocketAddress is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.net.SocketAddress.<clinit>(SocketAddress.java)
at net.spy.memcached.AddrUtil.getAddresses(AddrUtil.java:46)
...
```

I've read in the Play! Google Group that it's possible to use Cache in GAE with memcached. Do I have to set a different host for GAE, or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are confused by the [memcached](http://memcached.org/) and [Memcache on GAE](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/).

Memcache (JCache or low-level) is the cache APIs on GAE, it is a cross-instances cache service.

Comment: You are right, disabling memcached seems to work in GAE. However, looking at Quota Details doesn't seem to use Memcache API calls, although it's supposed to do so in production mode (as said in this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/4b4fc1830c90a6f3). Thank you very much.